# How to use java with Braid framework example: pigtail?

Tags: java, node.js, corda

I try to define Braid server in java like this [repo](https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/pigtail#pigtail). And the following is my BootstrapBraidService class:

```
@CordaService
public class BootstrapBraidService extends SingletonSerializeAsToken{
    private AppServiceHub appServiceHub;
    private BraidConfig braidConfig;
    public BootstrapBraidService(AppServiceHub appServiceHub){
        this.appServiceHub = appServiceHub;
        this.braidConfig = new BraidConfig();
        // Include a flow on the Braid server.
        braidConfig.withFlow(ExtendedStatusFlow.IssueFlow.class);
        // Include a service on the Braid server.
        braidConfig.withService("myService", new BraidService(appServiceHub));
        // The port the Braid server listens on.
        braidConfig.withPort(3001);
        // Using http instead of https.
        braidConfig.withHttpServerOptions(new HttpServerOptions().setSsl(false));
        // Start the Braid server.
        braidConfig.bootstrapBraid(this.appServiceHub,Object::notify);
    }
}
```

However node startup without my setting, like port use default(8080) instead of my setting(3001). 
And NodeJS server fails to get services descriptor:

```
{ Error: failed to get services descriptor from
http://localhost:8080/api/
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) code: 'ECONNRESET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/' }
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Update:
[the node shell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o0GF.jpg)

Comment: Can you check a couple of things? 1. Does your node state that it has the app installed when it starts? 2. Have you run the client (you need to do this separately)?

Comment: 1. Yes, the node shell print "Braid server started on   :http://localhost:8080/api/" when it starts

Comment: 2. Yes, run the client separately in webstorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is because BraidConfig is an immutable class with a fluent API, but your code is using it as a classic mutable POJO which means none of your changes are being applied to the BraidConfig.

The following should work fine:

```
@CordaService
public class BootstrapBraidService extends SingletonSerializeAsToken{
    private AppServiceHub appServiceHub;
    private BraidConfig braidConfig;
    public BootstrapBraidService(AppServiceHub appServiceHub){
        this.appServiceHub = appServiceHub;
        this.braidConfig = new BraidConfig()
            // Include a flow on the Braid server.
            .withFlow(ExtendedStatusFlow.IssueFlow.class)
            // Include a service on the Braid server.
            braidConfig.withService(new BraidService(appServiceHub))
            // The port the Braid server listens on.
            braidConfig.withPort(3001)
            // Using http instead of https.
            braidConfig.withHttpServerOptions(new HttpServerOptions().setSsl(false));
        // Start the Braid server.
        braidConfig.bootstrapBraid(this.appServiceHub,null);
    }
}
```

regards,
Fuzz